# how to access TextView content in xml file to java file in Android

Tags: android

some1 post the code for accessing .txt file available in my res folder

the code for which can be written in .java file!!!

---

This is the LogCat output when i get that error!!

07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.vogella.android.test/de.vogella.android.test.test}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at de.vogella.android.test.test.(test.java:55)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
07-01 14:50:20.886: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(257):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the file in your assets folder and then open it to read like you would in any other Java program.

Example [here](http://help4android.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-easily-access-included-files-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

try { InputStream raw = cntxt.getAssets().open("hello.text"); Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8")); fileContent = is.toString(); }catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } i wrote the above piece of code in the constructor of my .java file (the class that is extending Activity) it did nt give any compile error but as soon as i try to open the app on my emulator it crashes it shows app has stopped unexpectedly. why so?? is there anthyng wic is nt defined smwhr n is null??

Answer (score 0):

try
        {
            InputStream raw = cntxt.getAssets().open("hello.text");
            Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8"));
            fileContent = is.toString();
         }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }